# Script give user token error on OpenCart 2.3.0.2

Tags: php, opencart2.3

This Script is not working on opencart 2.3.0.2 can any one help to translate this?

Is there a problem with user token?

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function refudt(ele){
var pid = $(ele).data('pid');
var type= $(ele).data('type');

$.ajax({
url: 'index.php?route=sale/order/getprice&user_token=
{{ user_token }}',
dataType: 'html',
type: 'post',
data: 'order_id={{ order_id }}&pid=' + pid+'&type='+type,
success: function(html) {
$(ele).parent().append('<br>'+html);
}
});

}

function saver(ele){
var pid = $(ele).data('pid');
var price = $(ele).parent().find('input').val();
var type= $(ele).data('type');
confirm('Save new value: '+price +' ?');

$.ajax({
url: 'index.php?route=sale/order/getprice&user_token=
{{ user_token }}',
dataType: 'html',
type: 'post',
data: 'order_id={{ order_id }}&pid=' + pid+'&value='+price+'&type='+type,
success: function(html) {
$(ele).parent().remove();
if($('.rebus').length<1) {
location.reload();
}
}
});
}

//--></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you use twig function for OC2.3 version. This OC version does not suport twig. And instead `user_token` should be just `token`. Script you need change to:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function refudt(ele){
var pid = $(ele).data('pid');
var type= $(ele).data('type');

$.ajax({
url: 'index.php?route=sale/order/getprice&token=<?php echo $token; ?>,

dataType: 'html',
type: 'post',
data: 'order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>&pid=' + pid+'&type='+type,
success: function(html) {
$(ele).parent().append('<br>'+html);
}
});

}

function saver(ele){
var pid = $(ele).data('pid');
var price = $(ele).parent().find('input').val();
var type= $(ele).data('type');
confirm('Save new value: '+price +' ?');

$.ajax({
url: 'index.php?route=sale/order/getprice&token=<?php echo $token; ?>,
dataType: 'html',
type: 'post',
data: 'order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>&pid=' + pid+'&value='+price+'&type='+type,
success: function(html) {
$(ele).parent().remove();
if($('.rebus').length<1) {
location.reload();
}
}
});
}

//--></script>
```

Also do not forget that token should be defined on corresponding controller file like this: `$data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];`

Comment: I needed to change to this to make it work?  url: 'index.php?route=sale/order/getprice&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>',

Comment: default version of the OC 2.3 do not have function `getprice` in admin/controller/sale/order.php file. So I don't know what you have there..